# Why is position: fixed creating whitespace when I use it?

Tags: html, css

So I have been busy with a navbar and I want to make it fixed but whenever I use position: fixed, the navbar does stay fixed but it creates whitespace and pushes everything down (the parent container and it's sister elements).

So what could be causing this and how do I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help.

[Screenshot of how it looks with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRVbN.jpg)

[The HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaNNV.png)

[The CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P0Tx.png)

```css
nav {
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.hero-section {
  background-image: url(img/dylann-hendricks-Ll-A9nKuOhk-unsplash.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code> 
<section class="hero-section">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">KM</div>

        <div class="links-container">
          <div><a href="#about-scroll">About</a></div>
          <div><a href="#skills-scroll">Skills</a></div>
          <div><a href="#project-scroll">Projects</a></div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="intro-container">
        <div class="greeting rev-block"><span>Hi there,</span></div>
        <div class="my-name rev-block" id="onemore1">
          <span>I'm Khanya Mateta</span>
        </div>
        <div class="job-title rev-block" id="onemore2">
          <span>Front End Developer</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-btn"><a href="#contact-scroll">Contact Me</a></div>
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="img/github.png" />
          <img src="img/linkedin.png" />
          <img src="img/twitter.png" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </section>
 </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Are `<pre>` and `<code>` supposed to be there, wrapping everything?

Comment: I just put it there because I kept on getting an error when I was trying to post this question, but it's not part of my original code. I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in the css for nav element:

```css
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Adjust the `left` and `right` values while using `position: fixed`.

Using this I solved the same issue in my site.
Thank you .

Comment: @Khanya If this is the most suitable answer, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027611) the answer by clicking the check mark